# Cannot GET image from HTTP request

Tags: html, ajax, jquery, get, httprequest

I already check image and they do exist on the server.

I have include image in CSS rule with this code

```
.Invite{background: url("../images/interface/Shop/Btn_Ad_Invite_all.png") 0px 0px;}
.Invite:hover{ background-position-x: -86px; }
.Invite:active{ background-position-x: -172px; }

<div class="Button Invite" onclick="invite()"></div>
```

and I'm trying to use jQuery Ajax get and try to inject image to body with this code in browser console

```
$.get("https://fb.spot-the-differences.com/test/images/interface/Shop/Btn_Ad_Invite_all.png");
$.get("images/interface/Shop/Btn_Ad_Invite_all.png");
$("body").append("<img src='https://fb.spot-the-differences.com/test/images/interface/Shop/Btn_Ad_Invite_all.png'/>");
$("body").append("<img src='images/interface/Shop/Btn_Ad_Invite_all.png'/>");
```

All my browsers (IE, Firefox, Chrome) says fail to get image with no response.
And other computer in my local network can get image without problem.

If I copy image url and paste in to browser address I can receive image without problem:

[image]

Can someone please explain to why this happen and how to solve this problem I don't want this to happen to client on my site.

I would appreciate any kind of conversation or help.

I found suspicious thing when I try to change path of my problematic images to any inaccurate path I still got status failed instead of 404 not found like this one

```
<img src='http://google.Shop/Btn_Ad_Invite_all.png'/>
```

[jsfriddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fQK5K/1/) I see IMG4 same as IMG2 nothing appear even image broken icon

I need some advice thank so much.

Comment: Why would you want to use an AJAX call to get an image?

Comment: If you want to dynamically load an image, you just need to set the `src` property of an `img` element to the URL of the image. The browser will take care of the rest.

Comment: JQuery's $.get() isn't really meant for this purpose.

According to their documentation, $.get() is for xml, json, script, or html.

Comment: Thank for suggestion, I download it direct from css rule but it same failed as ajax call and I can't use src property because image have hover and active mouse.

Comment: I don't really mean to dynamical load image my image. And I have only 2 problematic images and other image in the same directory RESPONSE OK.
I try use ajax to make HTTP GET request and it RESPONSE in OK except my 2 problematic images. 
Please help and thank so much.

Comment: should I change question topic according to what I inquire , thank

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using a separate protocol than the web page (HTTPS vs HTTP) which can cause cross domain security issues in browsers.  Try either:

```
 $.get("http://fb.spot-the-differences.com/test/images/interface/Shop/Btn_Ad_Invite_all.png");
```

or this should work agnostic of page protocol

```
$.get("/test/images/interface/Shop/Btn_Ad_Invite_all.png");
```

If your goal is to dynamically display images, I do agree with some of the comments though set 
the src attribute of image tag and use css to position sprite.  For example:

```
 $('img').attr('src', '/test/images/interface/Shop/Btn_Ad_Invite_all.png');)
```

Comment: still failed I have even try to direct append image to body like this
$("body").append("<img src='http://fb.spot-the-differences.com/test/images/interface/Shop/Btn_Ad_Invite_all.png'/>");
and still get failed response

Comment: try $(body).append("<img src='/test/images...'>") it looks like that path may not resolve.  Or you can do the full http://fb.spot-the-differences/test/images...

Comment: All failed I'm so tired  and this problem occur only with my computer. I really really want to know the cause

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fQK5K/  although I do it like this I still can't see and load IMG2 but IMG3 work fine.

Comment: I can see IMG2.  Do you have an anti-virus/spyware that may be causing this?